# Sorting a matrix by column

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, matrix, tensorflow.js

I have a matrix which looks like this:

```
[[5,2],
[4,3],
[3,4]]
```

Using the command

```
tf.tensor([...])
```

And I would like to the matrix by the column with index 0, so that it will look like this:

```
[[3,4],
[4,3],
[5,2]]
```

How would I do that using Tensorflow.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the example, the tensor is sorted over the first axis.

Currently, there is no yet `tf.sort` in tensorflow.js. But to achieve the same thing, we can slice the tensor over its first axis, then sort it and get the indices. With the later, we can sort the initial tensor using tf.gather

```
a = tf.tensor2d([[3,4], [4,3],[5,2]])
firstAxis = a.gather([0], 1).reshape([-1]);
ind = tf.topk(firstAxis, a.shape[0]).indices
a.gather(ind.reverse(), 0).print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple javaScript:

```js
let arr = [[5,2], [4,3], [3,4]];

let result = arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry I did not add enough detail concerning how I created the tensor, the tensor was created using tf.tensor([[5,2],[4,3],[3,4]])

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question and used some of edkeveked's answer to come up with these two functions. They look awkward (and probably one can improve on the performance) but they get the job done for a 2D-matrix.

```js
const sortRows = (matrix, asc = true) => {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        const vector = matrix.reshape([-1])
        const topk = tf.topk(matrix, matrix.shape[1]).indices
        const inds = tf.add(topk, tf.range(0, matrix.shape[0] * matrix.shape[1], matrix.shape[1]).mul(tf.ones([matrix.shape[1], matrix.shape[0]])).transpose()).reshape([-1]).cast("int32")
        const sorted = vector.gather(inds).reshape(matrix.shape)

        return asc ? sorted.reverse(1) : sorted
    })
}

const sortColumns = (matrix, asc = true) => sortRows(matrix.transpose(), asc).transpose()
```

Running the following commands

```js
m = tf.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 5, 4], [-2, 1, 6]])
sortColumns(m).print()
```

will give you

```
"Tensor
    [[-2, 1, 1],
     [1 , 2, 3],
     [3 , 2, 4],
     [3 , 5, 6]]"
```